# Python classes hierarchy and design issues

Tags: python, oop, class

I have some python application that is chat server. It has multiple rooms and one client can be connected to one room. So I have class Room and class Client. Client has events like on_open(), on_message() and on_close() and also send() function. After receiving message I need to send it to other clients in room and post it to my message queue. Here is my problem. I don't know in which class do what.
Should posting to queue occur in Room class or in Client class?

Where should I broadcast message to other clients, in Client class or in Room class?

 Or maybe I should pass ALL events from Client class upper to Room class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should let the queue manage its own concerns and just let it listen for the events it needs to record, rather than subordinating it to either of the other classes.

You might want to read up on the Observer pattern (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/131499-observer-pattern/  and http://philipuren.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/4-guid.html).  It's designed for  situations where many different classes might want to respond to some state change (in your example, an incoming message). In this case, your Client class would be the 'Subject' - it would keep a list of classes that care when something like an on_open() occurs and let them know that something has happened; the Observers (in this case, I'm suggesting the Queue) decide what to do with that information on their own.  This enhances future flexibility, since you don't need to change existing classes if you want to add a new functionality like creating a desktop notification or playing a sound when the message comes in.

This example, which implements Observer with a decorator, gives you an idea of how much future flexibility you can win with this strategy: http://reader1000.tumblr.com/post/20361533339/observer-pattern-with-python-decorators

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The queue should be in the Room as each Client is not in charge of the queue, but in order for the clients to see the messages they should be able to see the queue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However Client doesn't need to see the queue because queue is for archiving purposes and is done by another process.

Comment: Without a queue of messages how would all of the other clients see messages?

My only other thought would be: each time a message comes in the Room sends a message out to every client, but that seems cumbersome.

Comment: And that is how it is done right now. Client can receive events and it passes message upper to room.